# LaTeX: Reverse row count or enumerate over tabular rows

Tags: tables, enumerate, count

I'm drafting my CV and I would like to number the projects, conferences, etc. that I have done but in reverse order (ie: the newest has the highest number and is on top of the list). I found a code that row counts and one the enumerates, but I can't seem to get one that works in reverse over a number of rows.

What I'd like is basically three columns `{C{2m} L{8.5cm} R{6cm}`. Here's some code I'm using to control LaTex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%tabular

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Conferences}

%row count

\adjustbox{bgcolor=white, tabular=@{\stepcounter{rowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\therowcount.)}\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}>{\color{black}}l>{\color{black}}l}
{% 
National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017.
\\
McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016.
\\
TRIO Graduates School Retreat and Seminar. Delavan, October &2016
\\
Regional Materials and Manufacturing Network Conference. Menomonie, WI. &Spring 2016.
\\
Biotechnology and Molecular Biology On-Site Seminars. Madison, WI.& March 2015.
\\}

 %manual enumerate

\begin{enumerate}
\item[5] new
\item[4] aged
\item[...] old
\item[1] ancient
\end{enumerate}

%Table

\begin{tabular}{| C{2cm} | L{4cm} | R{4cm} |}
no &
Thing &
Date \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A fast fix is to use instead of `\stepcounter{rowcount}` the next: `\addtocounter{rowcount}{-1}` and to give a command like `\setcounter{rowcounter}{32}` just before starting the table [not tested] [use your current number of projects.]... Of course can be automated but I don't see the reason here

Comment: Another idea: Use `etaremune` as package, that counts enumerates in reverse order, but I did not check whether this really works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility by 'exploiting' a linear map between the total number of rows (being queried by `\getrefnumber`) and the current row counter value.

Using

```
f(x) = -x + N + 1
```

will map the current row number  to the reversal position, given that `N` marks the total number of rows.

This is done with `\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{thelastrowcount}+1 - \value{rowcount}`, provided that `\thelastrowcount` is a valid label being put after the tabular.

For this approached, I have to make a fake label that is not lost in the table cell group, i.e. using `\protected@xdef\@currentlabel`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


%tabular

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}


\subsubsection*{Conferences}

%row count

\adjustbox{bgcolor=white, tabular=@{\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{thelastrowcount}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}>{\color{black}}l>{\color{black}}l}
{% 
National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017.
\\
McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016.
\\
TRIO Graduates School Retreat and Seminar. Delavan, October &2016
\\
Regional Materials and Manufacturing Network Conference. Menomonie, WI. &Spring 2016.
\\
Biotechnology and Molecular Biology On-Site Seminars. Madison, WI.& March 2015.
\\ }
\label{thelastrowcount}

 %manual enumerate

\begin{enumerate}
\item[5] new
\item[4] aged
\item[...] old
\item[1] ancient
\end{enumerate}

%Table

\begin{tabular}{| C{2cm} | L{4cm} | R{4cm} |}
no &
Thing &
Date \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update for the desired table**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10.5pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


%tabular

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fakelabel}[1]{%
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{#1}%
}
\makeatother


\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{N}[2]{>{\raggedleft\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{#1}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#2}}

\begin{document}


\subsubsection*{Conferences}

%row count

\adjustbox{bgcolor=white, tabular=@{\refstepcounter{rowcount}\fakelabel{\therowcount}\makebox[3em][r]{\color{black}\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{thelastrowcount}+1 - \value{rowcount}.)}\hspace*{\tabcolsep}}>{\color{black}}l>{\color{black}}l}
{% 
National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017.
\\
McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016.
\\
TRIO Graduates School Retreat and Seminar. Delavan, October &2016
\\
Regional Materials and Manufacturing Network Conference. Menomonie, WI. &Spring 2016.
\\
Biotechnology and Molecular Biology On-Site Seminars. Madison, WI.& March 2015.
\\ }
\label{thelastrowcount}

 %manual enumerate

\begin{enumerate}
\item[5] new
\item[4] aged
\item[...] old
\item[1] ancient
\end{enumerate}

%Table

\begin{tabular}{| N{foocount}{2cm} | L{4cm} | R{4cm} |}
\multicolumn{1}{|C{2cm}|}{no} &
Thing &
Date \tabularnewline
&National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017.
\tabularnewline
&McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016.
\tabularnewline
&TRIO Graduates School Retreat and Seminar. Delavan, October &2016
\tabularnewline
&Regional Materials and Manufacturing Network Conference. Menomonie, WI. &Spring 2016.
\tabularnewline
&Biotechnology and Molecular Biology On-Site Seminars. Madison, WI.& March 2015.
\end{tabular}\label{foocount}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much!! I like this method a lot. I am able to better configure the code to fit different sections of the CV and it works very easily with tabular commands like 'longtable' and 'extrarowheight' as well, since some of the tables I have go on and on and the spacing was very tight between compendium items too. I only wonder, is it possible to align the numbers at top rather than center? NBD tho! Thanks again!

Comment: By changing the 'm' to 'p' in the preamble '\newcolumntype' code, you can align vertically.

Comment: @MatthewOlson: Yes, I know that .... but that wasn't in your question, was it?

Comment: No it wasn't but I did ask about it in the first comment, thank you, but found the answer myself before a response, so I was answering my own question in case someone else reads this and was wondering the same... thankx!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what `\adjustbox` is for, so I did with a standard `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=16.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{rowcount}
\newcounter{cvcount}

\newenvironment{cvdata}
 {%
  \par\noindent
  \stepcounter{cvcount}%
  \setcounter{rowcount}{0}%
  \edef\thiscvdatacount{\getrefnumber{cvdata@\thecvcount}}%
  \begin{tabular}{
    @{\stepcounter{rowcount}\cvdataitem}
    p{12.5cm}
    @{}
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
    @{}
  }%
 }
 {%
  \end{tabular}%
  \refstepcounter{rowcount}\label{cvdata@\thecvcount}%
 }
\newcommand{\cvdataitem}{%
  \makebox[1cm][r]{%
    \the\numexpr\thiscvdatacount-\value{rowcount}\relax.)\enspace
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Conferences}

\begin{cvdata}
National Conference on Undergraduate Research (NCUR). Memphis, TN.& April 2017
\\
McNair National Research Conference. Delavan, WI. October &2016
\\
TRIO Graduates School Retreat and Seminar. Delavan, October &2016
\\
Regional Materials and Manufacturing Network Conference. Menomonie, WI. &Spring 2016
\\
Biotechnology and Molecular Biology On-Site Seminars. Madison, WI.& March 2015
\end{cvdata}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set a label at the end of the `cvdata` environment and at the later compilation do the necessary computation.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure either. I'm a chemist, not a physicists, so my coding skills is 20 year old HTML and spaghetti -- throw it at something at it and see if it sticks.... But it's probably relevant for another function in the paper. But thanks for the advice on this. I appreciate your suggestion, but it was difficult to manipulate the fxn to adjust to other parts of my CV and style, whereas the other answer is very simple cooking.

Comment: @MatthewOlson: Very simple cooking?  I am using the same approach basically like in this answer, in a different order